# ı want to auto resize my app when i run it on another pc

Tags: tkinter

I want to run my app on my phone but when I run it on my phone the size and place of the frame change

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root=tk.Tk()
frame=Canvas(root, bg='green', width=100,height=100)
frame.place(x=200, y=250)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried. Also, you don't need both `import tkinter as tk` *and* `from tkinter import *` - best practice is to use only `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: I have tried on my pc and phone ı have created to vaules for pc but when i run it in phone the frame get bigger. I want to use page and frame in a a ratio as pc

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional details, don't just post them as comments. That said, you should look into `root.winfo_screenwidth()` and `root.winfo_screenheight()` - these methods will get the width and height of your device's screen in pixels, respectively.

Comment: guys ı know ı have asked a lot of questions but can i convert my app to apk or can i use it on android?

Comment: Well first you should delete the `from tkinter import *` line. You should just use `import tkinter as tk` and the `tk.` prefix for all your widgets. Its better for a few reason that I will not go into here. Using `place()` is almost never what you want to use when adding widgets to your code especially if you have to resize windows. Lean to use `pack()` or `grid()`. You name your canvas as frame but you might be better off using an actual `Frame()`. To resize your screen you will probably want to use `winfo_screenwidth()` and `winfo_screenheight()` to set the geometry.

Comment: root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(winfo_screenwidth(),winfo_screenheight()) do you mean this?

Comment: @MehmetKılınçkaya at a glance yes formatting your geometry like that should do the trick. That grabs the current size of your window then makes your root window that size. By doing that (especially when using grid() and pack() properly) you widgets will all expand or contract to fit the new view within reason. Make sure you take the time to learn how to set up the column/row config weight for grid() and the expand for pack() depending on what you use.

Comment: @MehmetKılınçkaya How are you even running a Tkinter program on Android? Are you using a Windows phone or an emulator? Not sure what you mean by "I want to run my app on my phone."

Comment: I Run it on pydroid app but if it is possible i want  convert it to apk

Comment: Do you know anything about convert apk?

Answer (score 0):

`Tkinter` does not support mobile. If you have `Kivy` platform, then this will do for mobile.